# Understanding retain cycles within a function in swift, an example from Matt Neuburg's book

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class myDropBounceAndRollBehavior: UIDynamicBehavior {

    let v = UIView()
    init(view v: UIView) {
        self.v = v
        super.init()    
    }

    override func willMove(to anim: UIDynamicAnimator?) {
        guard let anim = anim else {return}
        let sup = self.v.superview!
        let grav = UIGravityBehavior() 

        grav.action = { [unowned self] in
            let items = anim.items(in: sup.bounds) as! [UIView]
            if items.index(of: self.v) == nil {
                anim.removeBehavior(self)
                self.v.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        self.addChildBehavior(grav)
        grav.addItem(self.v)
    }
}
```

Here we have a class with a function `willMove(anim:)` that has closure that references itself, creating a retain cycle. To resolve this issue, Matt sets `self` to `unowned self` to break the cycle.

His next paragraph says this:

> There's a potential (and rather elaborate) retain cycle here:
>   `self.addChildBehavior(grav)` causes a persistent reference to `grav`,
>   `grav` has a persistent reference to `grav.action` and the anonymous
>   function assigned to `grav.action` refers to `self`. To break the
>   cycle, I declared the reference to `self` as `unowned` in the
>   anonymous function's capture list

With that extract from the book, I drawn up reference graph for the situation below,

[image]

So, when the function `willMove(anim:)` is triggered, the function call `self.addChildBehavior(grav)` that references `grav` will be created, creating a strong reference to the `grav` reference instance. but since function `willMove(anim:)` lives on the main thread, the function `self.addChildBehavior(grav)` **has to** finish before releasing the heap memory for `willMove(anim:)`, therefore `self.addChildBehavior(grav)` not longer has a strong reference to `grav`, and `willMove(anim:)` can finish and memory is released from the heap. The result will look like this:

[image]

At this point, once `willMove(anim:)` has finished executing, the only references remaining is the `unowned self` referring to the instance and some reference (e.g. `let behavior = MyDropBounceAndRollBehaviour()`), and then once the anonymous function has finished executing, then it will only be `behaviour` referencing the `<MyDropAndBounceBehavior>`

Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: @matt This one is for you

Comment: The ownership cycle is never broken. It's `self -> behaviors -> grav -> action -> self`. You never remove the behavior from `self`, you never remove `grav` from behaviors and you never set `grav.action` to `nil`. Therefore it's not broken.

Comment: Yeah, if he wants to ask about my code, I don't get why he doesn't ask me directly. It's not like I'm hiding or anything. My email address is plastered all over the Internet. Plus I'm here too. (OTOH good old Sulthan seems to be handling this just fine!)

Comment: You (Brendon) might want to read chapter 5 of my _other_ book, which discusses retain cycles due to retained self-referential functions. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#SECweakSelf

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the ownership cycle in other words:

```
self.behaviors -> grav -> action -> self
               ^ created by addChildBehavior(grav)
                       ^ created by grav.action = {
                                  ^ created by capturing
```

`self` owns the gravity behavior. The gravity behavior owns the action and the action captures (owns) `self`.

To break the ownership cycle, you have to break one of the connections. 
One solution is to break capturing by using `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]`.

Your reasoning is wrong. When a function call (e.g. `willMove`) is finished, no heap memory is freed. Heap memory in reference-counting memory management is released only if there are no more owners of that memory. Since the ownership cycle exist, the memory cannot be released. Threads don't really have any role in this. The same situation would happen if everything was called on the same thread (which actually can happen).

I think that your main mistake is the idea that `self.addChildBehavior(grav)` retains `grav`. That's not true. It permanently adds `grav` to a list of behaviors held by `self`, which means creating a strong ownership `self -> grav`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help:

Self owns `grav` (added as a child behavior). But `grav` has a block that owns `self` (action). So now you have `self` that owns `self`, and that's a retain cycle. You can use `unowned self` here because if `self` gets deallocated, `grav`'s block will too. You typically use `unowned self` in cases like this when `self` owns the object referring to `self`; otherwise, use `weak self`.